# Constructors and conversions

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion, composition, uniform-initialization

**C++**

I’ve [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448.aspx) that constructors without the `explicit` keyword and with **one** parameter (or a **one**-argument call to a ctor with several parameters, where all but **one** have default values) can perform one implicit conversion. Given two classes where `Foo`’s ctor has **two** `int` parameters and `Bar`’s ctor has **two** `Foo` parameters, that statement seems to imply a call to `Bar`’s ctor with two unqualified sets of `int`s should not translate into a call to `Bar`’s ctor with two `Foo`’s. Then, why does the following compile?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo first_, Foo second_) : first(first_), second(second_) {}
    Foo first;
    Foo second;
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Bar b = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    std::cout << b.first.x << ", " << b.first.y << ", ";
    std::cout << b.second.x << ", " << b.second.y << std::endl;
    // ^ Output: 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement implies nothing of the sort. It is a statement about constructors with one parameter, and you have written constructors with two parameters. It doesn't apply.

Any conversion sequence can contain at most one user-defined conversion (which, depending on the context of the conversion, may or may not be allowed to be `explicit` -- in the case you describe it may not). Here there are two separate conversion sequences: one to get from the initializer list to the first argument of `Bar`'s constructor, and another to get from the other initializer list to the second argument. Each sequence contains one conversion, to `Foo`. That's why your code is fine.

What you can't do under the "one user-defined conversion" rule is this:

```
struct Foo { Foo(int) {} };
struct Bar { Bar(const Foo&) {} };
struct Baz { Baz(const Bar&) {} };

Baz baz(1);
```

because that would require two user-defined conversions in the chain. But `Baz baz(Foo(1));` is fine since only one conversion is needed to get from the argument you provided (an instance of `Foo`) to an argument `Baz` can accept (an instance of `Bar`). `Baz baz(Bar(1L))` is also fine, because although there are two conversions `long -> int -> Foo` in order to get from `1L` to an argument that `Bar()` can accept, one of the conversions is builtin, not user-defined.

You also can't do this:

```
Bar bar = 1;
```

because that's copy-initialization and it first tries to convert the right-hand-side to `Bar`. Two user-defined conversions are needed in the chain `int -> Foo -> Bar`, so it's no good. But you can do this:

```
Bar bar = { 1 };
```

It's equivalent in this case to `Bar bar(1);`, not `Bar bar = 1;`. There is a difference in general between `T t = { 1 };` and `T t(1)`, which is that with `T t = { 1 };` the `T` constructor cannot be explicit. But it doesn't count as part of the conversion chain for the initializer.

Comment: +1 for thorough answer,but I’d appreciate a bit more clarity. For
“… to get from the initializer list…”: do you mean language’s built-in `braced-init-list` or the `STL`’s `std::initializer_list<T>`? As for “Each sequence contains one conversion, to `Foo`”: If you were to make that into your arrow diagrams, it would be `int -> Foo`, with **one** arrow, and not having another arrow to `Bar` whose constructor accepts `Foo`. Thus shouldn’t your “…`int -> Foo -> Bar`…” instead be like: “…`int -> Foo (subscript: temporary Foo from perspective of Foo’s copy ctor) -> Foo (subscript: after copying)`…”?

Answer (score 2):

The article you linked is written in terms of pre-C++11 version of the language, which completely ignores the new C++11 features related to uniform initialization. In older versions of the language user-defined conversions could be used implicitly to convert from a *single* object only.

In C++11 it became possible to use multi-parameter constructors to construct (and implicitly convert) objects from initializer of the `{ ... }` form, where each consecutive element from between the `{}` is passed as the corresponding constructor argument. This form of implicit conversion can also be disabled by `explicit` keyword.

This C++11 conversion is exactly what happens in your sample code. First, the `{ 1, 2 }` initializer is converted to `Foo` type using this new C++11 feature. Then the `{ Foo(1,2), Foo(3, 4) }` is converted to `Bar` type through the same C++11 feature.

The code you posted will not be accepted by a pre-C++11 compiler. In fact, pre-C++11 compilers prohibit  using `{ ... }` initializers with objects that have user defined constructors, except for the situations when there's only one value inside the `{}`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Pointing out the datedness of the MSDN article’s context clears up many issues. But the accepted answer pointed out more caveats I didn’t know about, preventing more usage pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, a `Foo` can be initialized from two integers:

```
Foo f = { 1, 2 };
```

It takes one construction to produce the first argument of `Bar` of type `Foo` from an `{ 1, 2 }`, i.e., `Foo{ 1, 2 }`. It takes another construction to produce the second argument of `Bar` of type `Foo` from `{ 3, 4 }`. Actually, there isn't any implicit conversion involved.

That said, please note that the number of conversions needed for different subexpressions don't count against the one conversion: if you have multiple subexpressions, each one involving one conversion to satisfy an argument, that's OK.

Comment: But the code does not convert `int` to `Foo`. And `Foo` has no conversion constructor from `int`.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl +1 for addressing the question with the fastest unedited answer. I recall your original answer stating something along the lines of: one conversion is allowed per sub-expression (or sequence?). The other users’ later answers/edits seem to harmonize with this thesis. If your only concern is the wording of "conversion" with respect to its historical emphasis on one argument rather than individual sets of arguments, would you mind bringing back and updating your original answer by adding that message?

Answer (score 1):

> Given two classes where Foo’s ctor has two int parameters and Bar’s ctor has two Foo parameters, that statement seems to imply a call to Bar’s ctor with two unqualified sets of ints should not translate into a call to Bar’s ctor with two Foo’s. Then, why does the following compile?

I am not sure how you got that implication, but it is the wrong way around: *if* `Foo`'s two int constructor were declared `explicit`, *then* the code would not compile, because the conversion from initializer list to `Foo` would not work:

```
 Foo f = {1,2}; // error if Foo(int, int) is explicit
```

Without the `explicit`, this conversion is allowed, and there is only one user-defined conversion taking place in the construction of `b`, that is, from initializer list to `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is a bit tricky:

```
Bar b = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

This is a statement that will try to build a `Bar`. It take the constructor of `Bar`:

```
Bar(Foo first_, Foo second_);
```

Ok, so it does need to build 2 `Foo`, no problem, let's see what the constructor of `Foo`is :

```
Foo(int x_, int y_);
```

Damn right ! We just got two `{ int, int }` ! As remarked by @juanchopanza, this is where the conversion occurs. I did not think of braced initializer list to (int, int) as conversion but as you can see if you put `explicit` on your constructor it is one:

```
converting to ‘Foo’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘Foo::Foo(int, int)’
   Bar b = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

Byt the way as pointed out in the comment, if you explicitly used `std::initializer_list` it does not compile: http://ideone.com/5enNFU

So it does build two `Foo` with those 2 initializers **converted** using your constructor, it does pass it to the `Bar` constructor, converting the initializer list containing two `Foo` :

```
Bar(Foo first_, Foo second_) : first(first_), second(second_) {}
```

And this constructor just call 2 copy constructor of `Foo` because `first` and `second` are of type `Foo`.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion. You can see that if you mark `Foo`'s constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: Yeah, from the initializer list, I didn't thought it was called a conversion, but GCC agrees with you on the term. I clarify immediatelly.

Comment: @juanchopanza Edited accordingly, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Johan By "...initializer_list to (int, int)...": do you mean `std::initializer_list<int>` or the language's built-in `braced-init-list` syntax? I'm not sure which one your compiler's error message means either. The code samples do not `#include <initializer_list>` directly or indirectly.

Comment: @CodeBricks No it does not work with initializer_list, it's only `braced-init-list`: http://ideone.com/5enNFU I clean the sentence ASAP.

Comment: @Johan : +1, Your compiler error demonstration is helpful, showing the usage difference between `braced-init-list` and `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @CodeBricks but that does surprise me... I thought it was the same concept behind, I have to check my standard :)